# Can't make links after make install successful

Tags: cmake

After install a package successfully, the tutorial says I have to make links if I want create links in /usr/local/bin. But:

```
ooker@ooker-Aspire-4741:~/gromacs-4.6.5/build$ sudo make links
make: *** No rule to make target `links'.  Stop.
```

I have to use `source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC` everytime to launch it, but it only available in the current shell. If I want to run it in another shell, I have to do again. Otherwise it will says the package is not installed.

This is the tutorial: http://www.gromacs.org/Documentation/Installation_Instructions_4.5#Final_Installation

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the answer.

Using

```
echo "source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC" >> ~/.bashrc
```

will work. It means that add the `source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC` command into your ~/.bashrc. This will make every new shell run the command automatically

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the correct folder when you're executing make links?
There should be `Makefile` file.
Do you have permissions to write in `/usr/local/bin` ?
If not, try `sudo make links`.

You can also make links manually:

```
ln -s /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC /usr/local/bin/GMXRC
```

Comment: I make links right after make install done. So if you mean the correct folder is the build folder, then yes. I had use sudo, as you can see that.

The command you give makes nothing changes. Should the path not to have space? I doubt that.

Comment: Make links won't work, you're referring to wrong manual.
But you can make an alias i.e
`echo "alias gxmrc='source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC'" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: It makes things strange. After I used that command, nothing changed. I though I need to re logon, so I did. Nothing changes, but now my tray icons are smaller than usual, and Qt programs like Konsole can now use IBus, which they don't before.

Comment: Hello? Are you there? Can you help me? I will delete this comment when you reply. Thanks in advance.